# xcode using json and POST to validate a username and password

Tags: ios, json, xcode, post

I am new to using POST, and have just written a code that takes a username and password that was entered in and sends it via POST for validation. If it is valid, it will return true, if not it will return false. I think my code works for the most part, but there must be something missing with my return data because it does not output true or false. Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)btnLogIn:(id)sender;
{
    //getting the username and password and putting it into a string
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username= %@ &password =%@",[self.lblUserName text],[self.lblPassword text]];

        //output the string
NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

//setting the URL to post to
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"myurl.php"];

    //converts string to data that can be used to post
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];


//get the length of the string
  NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

//formatting the URL
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLResponse *requestResponse;
NSData *requestHandler = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&requestResponse error:nil];

NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[requestHandler bytes] length:[requestHandler length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
```

}

I am not sure what part is missing or wrong. Everything runs fine, just returns blank when I test it out.

Comment: The space between the = and the & and 'password' doesn't look right to me.  I think you should have @"username=%@&password=%@"

Comment: @Paulw11 is right. Get rid of the spaces and URL-encode the string.

Comment: Hint: learn what Xcode is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is another method

```
  //Create the request

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myurl.php"]];
// create the Method "GET" or "POST"

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//Pass The String to server
NSString *userUpdate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",[self.lblUserName text],[self.lblPassword text],nil];

//Check The Value what we passed
NSLog(@"the data Details is =%@", userUpdate);

//Convert the String to Data
 NSData *data1 = [userUpdate dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//Apply the data to the body
[request setHTTPBody:data1];

//Create the response and Error

NSError *err;
NSURLResponse *response;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request      returningResponse:&response error:&err];

NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

//This is for Response 
 NSLog(@"got response==%@", resSrt);

 if(resSrt)
{
NSLog(@"got response");


}
 else
{
 NSLog(@"faield to connect");
 }
```

Comment: Wow this a lot more simple and understandable than what I was trying to put together. Thanks! :)